# Android scale a Bitmap

Tags: java, android

I want to have a big panorama Bitmap on my screen, that I can scroll with my finger. But I don't know how to scale it right:

`rectF.set(x, 0, x + [whatToPutHere], getMeasuredHeight)`
`canvas.drawBitmap(bmpBackground, null, rectF, null`

What do I have to put in `whatToPutHere` if I want it to have the right dimensions?

I hope you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved the problem myself:

I create the variable
`int dimension = getMeasuredHeight()/bmpBackground.getHeight();`
For `whatToPutHere` I put
`bmpBackground.getWidth()*dimension;`